# VPN, SSH, GitLab and composer update

Tags: ssh, https, composer-php, gitlab, vpn

When I try to update composer in project, I have a problem:
I work with VPN connection, and I haven't any access rights to work with gitLab on SSH. But I can work with project with usual https.
But composer updating try to use SSL and there is error:

```
Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@gitlab.***.net:***.git' '***.git/'
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I want to change updating wrom SSH to usual https.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

So you can use

```
git clone https://gitlab.***.net:***.git' '***.git
```

and then authenticate yourself  - your gitlab repository should have both git and https repository urls if you need to verify

Comment: I have already copied my project but it has dependencies on the other project. And composer updating try to download it. I need to say composer that it must use only https. Or say composer that I have this project local on my computer.

Comment: If you're on linux system or a mac there has to be file named id_rsa.pub (or another *.pub holding your public key - search those files and once found copy it's content to the list of known public keys in gitlab, alternatively generate a new one with sudo ssh-keygen -t RSA , and once generated copy this to your repository's settings

Comment: It's unaware of your clone unless you specify it like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638395/how-to-force-composer-to-use-https-instead-of-git

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the problem. I update my ssh key on the computer and add it to my gitlab profile. Now it works.